# What are good techniques for rewriting nested for loops in Haskell?

Tags: for-loop, haskell, nested-loops, code-translation, nested-for-loop

I'm learning Haskell and currently trying to rewrite this code:

```scala
  case class Coord(x: Int, y: Int)

  def buildBoard(coords: [Coord]): String = {
    var str = ""
    for (i <- 0 to 30) {
      for (j <- 0 to 40) {
        if (coords.exists(c => c.x == i && c.y == j))
          str += "x "
        else
          str += "o "
      }
      str += "\n"
    }
    str
  }
```

This builds a simple board for a command line game that i'm writing. What's the simplest way that I can rewrite this? I'm not looking for anything performatic

I'm using tuples to implement `Coord` type:

```
type Coordinate = (Int, Int)
type Coordinates = [Coordinate]
```

### Possible answer

I'm very grateful to those who helped. I managed to get the job done using list-comprehensions. My thought was to get rid of the "iteractive approach" of the previous code. In fact, I wanted to translate a "virtual" set of coordinates into a string, and here is how I did it:

```hs
createBoard :: Coordinates -> String
createBoard coordinates = concatMap parse board
  where
    parse coordinate@(_, y)
      | coordinate `elem` coordinates = "x "
      | y == 41   = "\n"
      | otherwise = "o "
                    
    board = [ (x, y) | x <- [0..30], y <- [0..41] ]
```

Comment: One of the idea's of functional programming (and by extend declarative programming) is that you should not think in terms of loops.

Comment: You could try to solve this using list comprehensions and/or `concat`. You should not attempt to mimic your imperative code closely, but to express the result in a functional way, e.g. by building a list-of-lists that you can concatenate later on to get the wanted result.

Comment: Also, this question shouldn't be closed. It can be useful for anyone who still getting through initial steps of fp and haskell itself, or people who is (as sweetly stated by the honorous user @AntC) "trying to rewrite crufty code".

Comment: yes, LCs are good for expressing nested loops. what did you use for the `coords.exists(c => c.x == i && c.y == j)` check? --- if you have the solution, you can post your own answer here when / if the question gets reopen. if not, you could edit it into the question, though this is not usually recommended ("usually" means, when the Q is open, post your own answer instead. :) ).

Comment: @AntC actually, SO has a [tag:code-translation] tag. :)

Comment: @WillNess Whose tag wiki says right there "NOTE that asking to have your code translated is not suitable for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @WillNess I used `elem`. @chi 's `concat` tip led me to `concatMap`, then I wrote a function that maps `[ (x, y) | x <- [0..30], y <- [0..40] ]` to a string. And sure! If the question gets reopened i'll be glad to post the code.

Comment: @amalloy it also says *'An appropriately formed question might be "How do I translate this statement"'* and the original title of the question was *"How can I rewrite nested for loops in Haskell?"*. looks pretty much the same. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already found out, the “nested loop” part can be largely done with a list comprehension.

But everything else in your original code can be done with a list comprehension as well! First use one list comprehension for the outer loop:

```
Prelude> [ "foo" | i <- [0..3] ]
["foo","foo","foo","foo"]
```

You don't really need to take care of the newline characters, simply use the standard [`unlines`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines) function

```
Prelude> unlines [ "foo" | i <- [0..3] ]
"foo\nfoo\nfoo\nfoo\n"
```

Now the inner loop. This should result in a single string/list, so you could `concat` the individual lists, but again there's a standard function that also adds the space that you always put between two characters:

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ unlines [ unwords ["a" | j <- [0..4]] | i <- [0..3] ]
a a a a a
a a a a a
a a a a a
a a a a a
```

And finally we can use a conditional to decide what character to use:

```
Prelude> putStrLn $ unlines [ unwords [if i>j then "x" else "o" | j <- [0..4]] | i <- [0..3] ]
o o o o o
x o o o o
x x o o o
x x x o o
```

Now let's wrap all this in a function:

```
createBoard :: Coordinates -> String
createBoard cs
 = unlines [ unwords [ if (i,j)`elem`cs then "x" else "o"
                     | j <- [0..40]
                     ]
           | i <- [0..30]
           ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops are what monads / do notation / list comprehensions *are*, in some sense.

Your task can be coded directly as one list comprehension, which will take care of all the testing, newline inserting, and concatting, corresponding pretty much directly to your "imperative" code which is not that imperative-looking if you squint a little:

```
board :: [(Int, Int)] -> String
board coords =
   [ c | i <- [0..30],                 -- outer loop
         j <- [0..40],                 -- nested loop
         c <- if elem (i,j) coords   
                then "x "              -- two chars
                else "o " ++           --   spliced in
              if j == 40               -- and an optional
                then "\n"              --   newline
                else "" ]
```

If your language's ranges are not inclusive of the upper bound (as Haskell's "ranges", i.e. enumerations, are), you will need to adjust that here.

There's no need to use any extraneous functions except for `elem` here. List comprehensions are pretty versatile. Especially the concatting is pretty much what they exist for in the first place: no matter how many nested loops there are, the element produced at the *innermost* level is just spliced right into the output. Just like with your `str += "x"` etc. statements.